# Problem with install command to copy a whole directory

Tags: shell, directory, file-copy, utilities, coreutils

So I have a repo with some of my [config files](https://github.com/nathdwek/myBin/tree/master/dotFiles) and I'm trying to create a `makefile` to install them in the homedir. The problem I have is that when I run the following command straight in bash

```
install -m 755 -d ~/path/to/dotfilesDir/ ~/
```

seemingly nothing happens while

```
install -m 755 ~/path/to/dotfilesDir/{file1,file2,...} ~/
```

works as intended.

Why doesn't the first (easier and cleaner) solution work?

Comment: Related: [Linux “install” command for wildcard installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2110933/95735)

Comment: I just used cp with -r. I really dont understand why install dont have -r option like cp has.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a look at the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?install), it seems that `install` will not do what you want.

Indeed, the Synopsis section indicates a usage of the form:

```
install [OPTION]... -d DIRECTORY...
```

and later on, the man page says:

> -d, --directory
>             treat all arguments as directory names; create all components of
>             the specified directories

So it seems to me that the point of this option is to be able to install a complicated (but empty) directory structure à la `mkdir -p ...`.

You can accomplish what you want with a loop:

```
for file in /path/to/DotFiles/dir/*;do
    install -m 755 "$file" ~/
done
```

Or, if there are many levels under `/path/to/DotFiles/dir`, you can use `find`:

```
find /path/to/DotFiles/dir/ -type f -exec 'install -m 755 "{}" ~/' +
```

Comment: Create all components of the specified directories = Create the subdirs but not the files?

Comment: @nathdwek Right. This way you can create a complex (skeleton) directory structure under, say, your home directory using `install -m 755 -d ~/foo/bar/baz`

Comment: `-exec 'install -m 755 "{}" ~/' +` is not going to work, at least not on certain (all? most?) version of linux. May work on OSX or something. Using something like this is pretty straight forward if you want a oneliner: 1. create directories recursive: `for d in $(find . -type d); do install -d --mode 755 "$d" "../install-test/$d"; done` 2. create files recursive: `for f in $(find . -type f); do install -D --mode 644 "$f" ../install-test/; done`

Answer (score 18):

Starting from @Joseph R.'s answer, this is my solution to make it work with find, as I couldn't make his command work. (I don't think it does, because of the rules applying to `\+`: there can be nothing after the `{}` element.) (I couldn't comment. This whole paragraph can actually be removed.)

To copy all the files into the exact same directory (here `target/directory`):

```
find directory/to/copy -type f -exec install -Dm 755 "{}" "target/directory" \;
```

`-D` is not mandatory here, it will just create the non-existing directories to the target.

To copy a whole directory hierarchy and its files (this will omit empty directories) starting from where you currently are:

```
find directory/tree/to/copy -type f -exec install -Dm 755 "{}" "target/directory/{}" \;
```

As said, this will recreate the tree starting from `$PWD`.
Also, if you need to copy the empty directory, on could find a way using the `-type d` of `find` and `install -d`.

So, in order to copy the tree, starting from a directory that is not `$PWD`:

```
(cd parent/directory && find directory/tree/to/copy -type f -exec install -Dm 755 "{}" "target/directory/{}" \;)
```

Notice how `parent/directory` isn't copied over.

**Extra**

For those using `shell/fish`, here's the line which does the same:

```
fish -c 'cd parent/directory; and find directory/tree/to/copy -type f -exec install -Dm 755 "{}" "target/directory/{}" \\;'
```

Answer (score -1):

Copy src folder and files in it to dst but I think install does not support recursive folder copy.

```
install -D src/* -t dst
```